# Check Swipe on Iframe don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, swipe

i was developen a wordpress theme/template,
I have a Iframe in the middle of the page with i want to check when the user swipe Left our Right to change between the posts.

I implements with Swipe jQuery Mobile for the Swipe detection

and i'm using this code:

```
$('#iframe-container').load(function(){

     var iframe = $('#iframe-container').contents();
     var iframeBody = iframe.find("#iframe-body");

     $(iframeBody).click(function(){
           console.log("click");
     });

     $(iframeBody).on("swiperight",function(){
           console.log("Swipe right");
     });

     $(iframeBody).on("swipeleft",function(){
           console.log("test left");
     });
});
```

This part work fine when clicked inside the iframe .

```
$(iframeBody).click(function(){
       console.log("click");
 });
```

But the part with Swipe doesn't work. Anyone know how to solution problem.

Very Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27917990/8196308

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/use-swipe-with-and-ifram-or-something-similar